# Jquery Datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have added a jquery datepicker on asp.net page. When I click on any button, the page postbacks and then the jquery datepicker stop working (It does not appear when I click on textbox linked to Jquery datepicker)

Please help & thanks in advance

I am using following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datepickerfrom").datepicker({
                constrainInput: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
            });

    $(".datepickerto").datepicker({
                constrainInput: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
            });
        });
```

Comment: please add code u have tried

Comment: Any error in Browser console ?

Comment: is the  datepicker input being changed after the postback? or any errors generated from that in console?

Comment: @Bhadra the value remains the same after I click on any asp.net button

Comment: can u provide the full javascript and html structure.and any other javascript u are using for post

Comment: are you using update panel?